# How to Achieve Multi-Tenancy with Flask, Flask-SQLAlchemy, and URL Prefix Handling

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, multi-tenant

have an application built with Flask and Flask-SQLAlchemy, and I'm looking to implement multi-tenancy by adding a <tenant_slug> prefix to every route. Currently, I have all routes defined with app.register_blueprint(web, url_prefix='/<tenant_slug>'), but this approach results in duplicated <tenant_slug> prefixes for every blueprint registered. I'm seeking advice on a more efficient way to handle this.

I've already implemented code to get the tenant_slug using Flask's @app.url_defaults and @app.url_value_preprocessor.

```
@app.url_defaults
def add_tenant_slug(endpoint, values):
    if 'tenant_slug' in values or not g.tenant_slug:
        return
    if app.url_map.is_endpoint_expecting(endpoint, 'tenant_slug'):
        values['tenant_slug'] = g.tenant_slug


@app.url_value_preprocessor
def pull_tenant_slug(endpoint, values):
    try:
        g.tenant_slug = values.pop('tenant_slug', None)
    except AttributeError:
        g.tenant_slug = "public"
```

This code works well for most scenarios, but when I attempt to change the schema for a new tenant, some models continue to query the old schema ("default") instead of the schema from the current tenant.

Here's the code I use to set the current schema for the ORM:

```
@app.before_request
def select_schema_by_tenant():
    db.session.execute(text('set search_path to "{}"'.format(g.tenant_slug)))
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to ensure that all models correctly query the schema associated with the current tenant and any suggestions for optimizing the handling of the <tenant_slug> prefix in my Flask application.